# Spring. ModelAttribute. GetMapping. THYMELEAF

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Program can't resolve objects that i give it in html from controller.

The Model

```
public class Taco {

    private String name;
    private List<String> ingredients;
}
```

The Ingredient

```
public class Ingredient {

    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final Type type;



    public static enum Type {
        WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE
    }

}
```

In Controller. I tried different variations of ModelAttribute in different methods, followed a lot of examples. But HTML still can't resolve.

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
public class DesignTacoController {



public void addIngredientsToModel(Model model) {
    List<Ingredient> ingredients = Arrays.asList(
            new Ingredient("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
            new Ingredient("COTO", "Corn Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
            new Ingredient("GRBF", "Ground Beef", Type.PROTEIN),
            new Ingredient("CARN", "Carnitas", Type.PROTEIN),
            new Ingredient("TMTO", "Diced Tomatoes", Type.VEGGIES),
            new Ingredient("LETC", "Lettuce", Type.VEGGIES),
            new Ingredient("CHED", "Cheddar", Type.CHEESE),
            new Ingredient("JACK", "Monterrey Jack", Type.CHEESE),
            new Ingredient("SLSA", "Salsa", Type.SAUCE),
            new Ingredient("SRCR", "Sour Cream", Type.SAUCE)
    );

    Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
    for (Type type : types) {
        model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(),
                filterByType(ingredients, type));
    }
}


@GetMapping
@ModelAttribute("design")
public String showDesignForm(Model model) {
    addIngredientsToModel(model);
    model.addAttribute("design", new Taco());
    return "design";
}


private List<Ingredient> filterByType(
        List<Ingredient> ingredients, Type type) {
    return ingredients
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getType().equals(type))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}}
```

Now part of design.html. Cant resolve protein, ingredient.id, ingredient.name. How can I fix this? I tried different ways:

```
<form method="POST" th:object="${design}">
   <div>
        <h3>Pick your protein:</h3>
        <div th:each="ingredient : ${protein}">
            <input name="ingredients"
            type="checkbox"th:value="${ingredient.id}" />
            <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it throw any exception? Now it seems to me that you have @GetMapping and you try to POST the form. Try to change @GetMapping to @PostMapping.

Comment: No exceptions, changed to @PostMapping, still cant resolve anything in html

Comment: How can i up my qust

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Program can't resolve objects" - that you don't even get to controller or that from controller you don't get back or everything is just working fine a you just don't see your values?

Comment: on html page a lot of things can't be resolved.(i write about it upper html snippet) => And browser cant render them

Answer (score 0):

You have to add getters and setters for Taco and Ingredient. 
If you use Lombok you can add class level annotation @Data. Lombok will generate it automatically.

```
@Data
public class Taco {

private String name;
private List<String> ingredients;
}
```

Comment: Forgot to say, i use lombok, so its ok. i just not included it here. tried all ur advices - nothing seems to help

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the constructor defined for the Ingredients or Taco classes. 
If you have not included that in the question  and you are getting an error on the POST call then try replacing your `@RequestMapping(value = "/design")` with `@RequestMapping(value = "/design", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

Comment: Forgot to say, i use lombok, so its ok. i just not included it here. tried all ur advices - nothing seems to help –